# Dynamo Database GSI

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am currently having a problem with solving the problem with dynamo db querying.

My dynamo db keeps track of changes in data. Thus partition key identifies which data i am changing

a single row looks something like this

```
partition key: servicename#resource#resource_id#region 

sortkey: current_time

changelogs: map of changelog (basically an array of changelog)

changer: who changed it
```

; It does great job when requesting one specific resource changes; however if i want to, say, query "I want to see last 30 minutes of changes in this servicename#resource *without specifying resource id*. Right now I only have scanning method at hand.. And i can't use scan due to large amount of data. I am open to all recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Your subject mentions the answer...even if your post doesn't.

Create a Global secondary index (GSI) with either the date or part of the date as the hash key and the time or remaining date part + time as the sort key.  If you have a large amount of data being created, you might want to include Hour in the hash key.

```
HK             SK
YYYY-MM-DD-HH  :MM:SS.00000
YYYY-MM-DD     HH:MM:SS.00000
YYYY-MM        DD-HH:MM:SS.0000
```